# Poner horario de inicio de un video en hml5

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo un código simple de  en html5:

```
<video width="800px" height="450px" preload="auto" autoplay>
    <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video1.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="video1.ogv" type="video/ogv">

    Tu navegador no soporta los vídeos de HTML5
</video>
```

Necesito que este video empiece a reproducirse todos los días a la misma hora.
Por ejemplo a las 14:30 UTC
No he podido lograrlo y no encuentro respuestas en la web.
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

no entiendo para que pero:

```js
setInterval(() => {
var d = new Date();
console.log(d.getHours()+":"+d.getMinutes());
 if( (d.getHours()+":"+d.getMinutes()) == "10:7"){ 
 document.getElementById("video").play();
  }
}, 3000);
```

```html
<video  width="320" height="176" id="video">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://download.blender.org/peach/trailer/trailer_400p.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta. Tengo 2 preguntas. El horario de 16:30 es el horario de mi servidor, el horario de mi PC o a que horario se refiere? Y la segunda pregunta es sobre }, 3000); Que significa ese 3000? Gracias mil.

Comment: Hola Bryro. He intentado tu ejemplo de varias formas, pero no funciona. Igual muchas gracias por el aporte

Comment: perdon me quedo el var d = new Date(); y la hora siempre era la misma para la primera ejecucion ya puedes probarlo!

Comment: El d = new Date(); esta en el primer ejemplo. Asi que sigo sin entender. Si me puedes enviar nuevamente el codigo correcto, me seria muy util. Gracias nuevamente.